# Configure programmatically Chart in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, crystal-reports-xi

I need to create a chart with a formula or change data axis values. It`s possible??

Comment: No, i know add chart in crystal reports for visual studio, but i can change my data axis (vertical) values (string values not numbers).

Comment: In your tutorial vertical axis are a summatory, i want show two string fields. For example names and dates.

Comment: Did you already tried something or you don't know from where to start?

Answer (score 0):

This similar to my solution. I have to settle...

[image]